# Intellij Missing "@android:theme"

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

This is the project's "style.xml. This was pre generated with the libgdx project setup. idea started to say that "@android:theme" is missing, and can't resolve "@android:style/Animation","@android:color/transparent".

```
<resources>
<style name="GdxTheme" parent="@android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">"@android:color/transparent"</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">"@android:style/Animation"</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

What I tried:
-invalidating caches
-delete workspace.xml
-delete the .idea folder
-reinstall Android SDK
-reinstall Intellij
-reload the project from gradle.

Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for a resources reference is `@<resource_type>/<resource_name>`. The format `@android:<resource_type>/<resource_name>` works the same way, but references a platform resource.

The issue with `@android:Theme` is that it lacks a resource type and the forward slash to delineate the type from the resource name.

Themes belong to the "style" resource type, so what you really want is this:

```
<style name="GdxTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

As far as the issues with `"@android:style/Animation"` and `"@android:color/transparent"`- those are both valid resource references, but the reference should not be surrounded by quotes. The quotes would make those into strings, not references. Just remove those and you should be good.

Comment: Okey, the parent is now fixed. The rest is still wrong :/

Comment: You should just be able to remove the quotes from around the two resource reference issues- just updated my answer to include that information.